# Any issue with running 240v and 120v THHN in the same conduit and can they share a ground?

Tags: electrical, conduit

Im running electrical for a mini split which requires a 240 line and there has to be a GFCI outlet near by so I'm running that too. The only way to get it there is through conduit (not buried) so I want to run both lines from the panel to the location and then probably a junction box to split them outside. Everything I've read says this is fine as long as I don't go over the capacity of the conduit which I'll probably do 1" for future proofing. Any issues, can they share a ground?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem doing what you want, as long as all the conductors and overcurrent devices are sized properly. As per National Electrical Code, you'll size the equipment grounding conductor (EGC) based on the largest overcurrent device used. Which means the EGC will likely be sized based on the size of the breaker protecting the 240 volt circuit.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 250 Grounding and Bonding
>
> **250.122 Size of Equipment Grounding Conductors.**
>
> **(C) Multiple Circuits.** Where a single equipment grounding
> conductor is run with multiple circuits in the same
> raceway, cable, or cable tray, it shall be sized for the largest
> overcurrent device protecting conductors in the raceway,
> cable, or cable tray. Equipment grounding conductors installed
> in cable trays shall meet the minimum requirements
> of 392.10(B)(l)(c).

Comment: Is there any issue with having the conduit terminate in a box that hosts the outlet and from there pull a flexible conduit to go to the compressor?

Comment: It's not a problem, as long as the box is big enough. You need to have a disconnect for the condensing unit. So you'd go from the box to the disconnect, then to the condensing unit. It's common to use a disconnect like the one shown in [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/28336/33).

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/33077/33), and [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/36710/33) may help you calculate what size box you need.

Comment: You need the disconnect because you can't just unplug? Is that required, couldn't you shut shut the breaker?

Comment: @RyanDetzel I think the rule is, if the condensing unit is not within sight of the breaker, you need a disconnect. But I could be wrong about that. So you're not working on the unit, and somebody flips on the breaker.

Comment: **National Electrical Code 2014 *440.14 Location.** Disconnecting means shall be located within sight from and readily accessible from the air conditioning or refrigerating equipment.*

Comment: Sounds like you might be in a bit over your head, and might want to consider contacting an Electrician.  Install the conduit and pull the conductors to the box, then let the Electrician (or HVAC technician) handle the hook up.

Comment: I had four quotes from electricians, not one of them mentioned the disconnect box. Interesting...